# I want to Add a table caption in html

Tags: html, html-table

Below is the code am using to create a basic table and i want to show a caption of the table using a any name.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>mark</td>
   <td>23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer.**

```
<table>
<caption>Table Caption</caption>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mark</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
</table>
```